# header image alignment coming wrongly in NavigationView android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, navigation-drawer

i have created Navigation View in my app.for header,i have added **image and  textview**.but those alignment are not coming properly.it always start above the screen of the mobile. 
Thanks in Advance.

**Here is my code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

**HeaderView:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/view_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

  <!--  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_header_bg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />-->

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="130dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"

            />

        <!--  <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/img_logo"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:layout_centerInParent="true"
              android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
              android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
              android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
              android:scaleType="fitXY" />-->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
        <TextView
          android:id="@+id/user_name"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/name"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        />
     </RelativeLayout>


        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
                android:background="@color/colorSpinnernavihead"
                android:visibility="gone">
            <Spinner
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:popupBackground="@color/colorWhite"
               android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
               android:backgroundTint="@color/colorBlack"
               android:id="@+id/spinner_navigation">

            </Spinner>

      </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear_1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_line"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorGrayNormal"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Check This answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40405060/views-overlapping-with-toolbar

Comment: that is different.my problem is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your code with this

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_logo"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img_logo"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: android:layout_centerInParent="true" this one i know but first it shouldn't come like this right? it should start from top only

Comment: what do you want to design? can you add your expected desing?

Comment: my question is why view is going out of the Screen.it should start from top properly right?

Comment: @SivabalanD  because drawer start with a 0 0 coordinates  and your content hiding behind the status bar

Comment: @SivabalanD that why you have to set marginTop to full fill your requirements

Comment: so how can i set my view below status bar?

Comment: @SivabalanD just add marginTop of your first view

Comment: because i want image and two textview in center of the parent.look wise on top less space only there. so i need to fix it

Comment: @SivabalanD you can add margin or change the status bar to transparent

Comment: @SivabalanD if my answer work for you than upvote and accept my answer

Comment: how much dp i need to give for status bar

Comment: 20dp to 24dp  but 24dp is best